# Visual Studio 2017 - Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I just upgraded my Visual Studio to the latest version (1/30/2017).
My ASP.NET Core project was working before the upgrade, but I now get the following error that stops me. Are there any simple solutions to this?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageDependencies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.LockFileCache.LoadLockFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.LockFileCache.GetLockFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.get_LockFile()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.ReadProjectFileDependencies()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue after upgrading today.

Comment: Check this thread https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16206

Comment: Check app.config for binding redirects

Comment: Just happened to me too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to create a new ASP.NET Core application, check its .csproj file and modify the old project based on it. A lot of things seem to have been removed and simplified and it's too much to list here.

Comment: but I get the same error in new created project. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes get this error.

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case, I did a Clean Solution, Tools/options/NuGet Package Manager/Clear All NuGet Cache(s), then a reboot.  Loading/building the project then worked.

Not sure how repeatable this is.  I'm quite sure my project worked the first time I loaded it, then failed, then worked again after these steps.  It has worked on 2 computers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running `dotnet build` in the Paket-Manager Console of VS Studio.

After the software was again debuggable